# Проблема со slash_command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
async def fraction_audit_rang(ctx, 
                              member:disnake.Member, 
                              operations: Option(name="operations", choices={"Повысить сотрудника": 1, "Понизить сотрудника": 2, 
                                                          "Назначить на должность": 3, "Снять с должности": 4}), 
                              reason,
                              rank: disnake.Role, 
                              designator_number: Option(name="designator",required=False)):
    timestamp=datetime.date.today()
    nik1=member.guild.name
    if operations == "Повысть сотрудника":
        await member.edit(nick=f"2 | {nik1}")
        await member.add_roles(rank)
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} ({nik1}) повышен на должность {rank}. По причине: {reason}. Дата: {timestamp}")
    if operations == "Понизить сотрудника":
        await member.edit(nick=f"2 | {nik1}")
        await member.add_roles(rank)
        await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} ({nik1}) понижен на должность {rank}. По причине: {reason}. Дата: {timestamp}")
```

В общем, проблема такая, что я хочу создать слеш команду с выбором операции(как на скрине) и в зависимости от выбора менялся конечный результат. Но у меня вылезает ошибка (см. скрин). И я не правильно сопоставляю равенство, и я хз как правильно это сотворить.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]